# Flag's 'other' box is too large (comment flagging)

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, design

I was going through the Triage review queue, when I came to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28078453/printing-all-combinations-of-a-string-c#28078453).
I acknowledge that the OP edited the code out of their comment to their question, but however before this their comment was:

[image]

Naturally I went to submit an `Other` flag as the comment needed to be removed (or edited into the question) and none of the default flag reasons apply, when I saw this:

[image]

The `Other` flag option's reason box is *too large*, you could probably say it *overflows* (pun intended).

This bug has been confirmed on:

- Chrome (39.0.2171.99m) on Windows 8.1 x64
- Chrome (39.0.2171.99m) on Windows 7 x64
- Firefox 35 on Fedora (*confirmed by [dirkk](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1451599/dirkk)*)
- Firefox 35 on Windows 7 x64 (*confirmed by [Compass](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2958086/compass)*)

This <strike>seems</strike> is <strike>to be</strike> an issue with the new design (*there seems to be so many faults with it at the moment, even after testing it here on Meta*) as I never noticed this issue on the old design.

This has been confirmed by visiting Information Security where a new design isn't active, this is what the box *should* look like:

[image]

Has this bug been noticed by anyone else, or perhaps is this just me?

In the end I flagged that comment as `Obsolete` as the question's owner edited their code out and replaced it with this, but it seems *mean* to flag it as `Spam`:

[image]

Comment: Confirmed for FF 35 (running Fedora) as well.

Comment: Confirmed in FF35 on Win7 x64 as well. I would assume it's not browser-specific or OS-specific at this point <_<

Comment: I can confirm that this happens on IE11x86 running on Windows 7 Home Premium x64 with default settings. This also happens on IE10-8 mode.

Comment: And also happens on Opera 26.0 (blink-based) on Windows 7 Home Premium.

Comment: What do you take Stack Overflow for? Your own personal website?  A "you say jump and they ask how high" service?  Please, *please* review all the posts on meta bugs as I'm pretty sure this question will be.... voted as a good question and the bug will probably get fixed soon.

Comment: Happens on Meta, too: http://puu.sh/eSWOl/11a7988e58.png

Comment: Actually, it's *too broad*. ;)

Comment: Confirmed on meta: Chrome 39.0.2171.71 (64-bit) and Rekonq 2.4.2 on Arch Linux. Doesn't seem to be browser specific at all.

Comment: @Scimonster Users thought you were serious on that: http://puu.sh/eVmfp/8fd1b36a24.png

Comment: Well, i guess a certain user has no sense of humor. :P

Comment: I personally like to see a developer or moderator comment here, since I suspect this post may simply go unanswered and go unnoticed.

Comment: Just confirmed on IE11

Comment: I believe this was fixed. is it still happening for you?

Comment: @Jin I can confirm that this is now fixed.